# Text positioning CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am currently working on a website.  I added all my text and gave it absolute positioning.  But when I adjust my browser window size, the text moves and gets all crumbled up.  How do I make it so it stays in the same place and adjusts size with the flow of the window?

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "staying on the same place"? Do you mean relative to the browser window, or relative to other divs? And isn't your problem with the resizing of the text? This can be solved pretty easy by adding a width to the div

Comment: You will have to post your html and css to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: We cant go for guessing.Please post the code

Comment: some code | Screen shots } welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative;` Out of all you should first form a container which defines your whole content sheet where you will put in all the `<div>`.